# Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of 'x'

Tags: forms, angular, runtime-error

I got this error when trying to use dynamic forms and then bundling all of my dynamic form structure into an ngModule.  Later I tried importing the module and I kept receiving this error.

environment:
Angular v2.1.0
Webpack v2.1.0-beta.25

Comment: delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to manually import all the components and services independently without bundling them into an ngModule. For some reason trying to use the bundled ngModule flat out wouldn't work.